# How to calculate a real number raised to an imaginary number

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

I'm trying to find how to calculate by hand a real number raised to an imaginary number, for example $3^i$, but I only find $i^i$.  How could I solve on paper a real number raised to an imaginary? Is there any technique?

Comment: $3^{i} = e^{i \ln(3)} = \cos(\ln(3)) + i \sin(\ln(3))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard technique for raising one number to another is extended to complex numbers. This standard technique, for example, to calculate $2^2$ consists of
$$
2=e^{\log2}
$$
so
$$
2^2=(e^{\log2})^2=e^{2\log2}.
$$
So using your example of $3$ and $i$,
$$
3^i=e^{i\log3}=\cos(\log3)+i\sin(\log3)\approx0.45+0.89i.
$$
The case of $i^i$
$$
i^i=(e^{i\pi/2})^i=e^{-\pi/2}\approx0.21.
$$

Answer (score 1):

In general $$z^w=e^{\log z^w}=e^{w\log z}$$.

Of course you need a branch of log.

So $$r^{iy}=e^{\log r^{ iy}}=e^{i y\log r}=\cos(y\ln r)+i\sin(y\ln r)$$ for $r\gt0$.

Here I used Euler's formula and properties of $e$ and $\log$.