# Demonstration of real number raised to imaginary

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

$$3^i=e^{i\ln(3)}.$$

Why is this equality true, could anyone demonstrate it?

There may be a place where it’s already been demonstrated.

I see a lot of the demos of $i^i$ but with real base transforming to $\ln(3)$ I didn’t find.

Comment: Check out Euler's Formula - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: This is by definition. For $a$ a positive real number and $z$ complex we just define $a^z = e^{z \ln a}$. The nontrivial fact is that this is consistent with the usual definition of the exponential if $z$ is real, which is just a matter of applying logarithm and exponent rules.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate a real number raised to an imaginary number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4537800/how-to-calculate-a-real-number-raised-to-an-imaginary-number) You already have asked this before.

Comment: It has been mentioned , but agaian : It is very important that we usually run into trouble, if we use the exponential rules and compelx numbers are involved. Concerning , $i^i$ , it is not uniquely defined. We must choose a branch to establish a value, usually the branch is chosen such that we get a real number.